# Getting the same element without changing it using Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq, collections

I have a method like this:

```
public List<Fruit> Traverse (IEnumerable<Fruit> collection, Action<Fruit> action)
```

I can do this:

```
Traverse (array, f => f.Text);
```

How can I call the action so I get the same element?

```
Traverse (array, f => f);
```

C# compiler doesn't allow me to do this.

EDIT:

```
List<Fruit> result = ...
foreach (Fruit fruit in collection)
{
    result.Add(fruit);
    action(fruit);
}
```

The method signature is fixed so I can't get anything else by just using an action, right? But what I need is to pass an action that does nothing so I get the whole result list.

Comment: What is the syntax error? Could be helpful.

Comment: Suggestion: if there's a compiler error involved, it helps to include that.

Comment: Sorry it said: "Error 1 Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement"

Comment: Are you sure that first one compiles? Isn't that trying to get the Text property for a System.String? What's that?

Comment: I don't understand how you're doing the first one.  Strings don't have a .Text property.  Are you sure that you copied and pasted the code correctly?

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake I replaced my not so obvious object with string, let me replace that.

Comment: Hrm.  Even what you have now shouldn't compile.  Fruit.Text is going to return a string, which will complain if you pass it to Action<Fruit>...

Comment: Maybe you are right, my example might be different. Maybe I can't project directly, but let me update the code.

Comment: Reed: In C#, assignment is technically an expression, not a statement.  Strange but true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isn't Action a delegate that returns nothing?  How about:

```
Traverse(array, e => {});
```

Comment: Joan, that you say "that works" suggests you're doing this wrong in the first place. It sounds like you want an member access expression rather than an action. Like JaredPar said.

Comment: Also I don't think I explained the question correctly, but updated it now.

Comment: This is the right answer now that we have the right question :)

Answer (score 1):

Your method declaration doesn't seem right...

If you have this:

```
public List<string> Traverse (IEnumerable<string> collection, Action<string> action)
```

You can't be passing in this:

```
Traverse (array, e => e.Text);
```

This would require that each element support a "Text" property.  String doesn't have a Text property.

If you passed an `IEnumerable<string>`, then `e => e` would evaluate to an `Func<string, string>`.  You're returning the string itself.

If you want an `Action<string>`, you need to do something with the string that doesn't return a value (e).

Comment: I think I am missing a few things. I actually want to get the result list (added more code), can I do it with Action? Also when you say e => e, it returns the string itself, but then you are collecting the result of the Func inside the method, right? I collect the traversed object directly, not the action.

Comment: So I guess the above code might be written better. Can you please tell me if I should use Func in this case, and if so, can you please write it using Func so I see the difference.

Answer (score 1):

You've set up your Traverse method wrong.  You need to use a generic signature here and a `Func<T>` return.

```
public List<T> Traverse (IEnumerable<T> collection, Func<T,T> del)
```

Comment: Thanks Jared. Why it's wrong? I could use generics but the traverse method has special traversing of Fruit objects. Also what's the difference between Func and Action? Which is better?

Comment: Func<...> returns a value.  Action<T> just performs an "action" on the object being passed in.  If you want to return from the delegate, you want Func.  If the delegate is just performing an "action" on each element, use Action

Answer (score 1):

`Action<string>` takes a string argument but returns nothing, similar to a method with the signature `void Foo(string bar)`.

If you're using your action parameter to populate the return value than you will need to replace your action with `Func<string, string>`, which takes a string parameter and returns a string, similar to a function with the signature `string Foo(string bar)`.